# Replacing - sign with + Query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried my best but ony little of it works, I want to replace - to + sing withing a specific query string in a category.

i want to replace

```
https://www.example.com/stack/?s=over-flow
```

**to**

```
https://www.example.com/stack/?s=over+flow
```

I have tried my best with the below code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)-(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

It works but it breaks other part of my site containing - sign in the url

I want it specifically on **/stack/?s=** only

Please help me out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule to target a specific query string with only single parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(s=[^&-]+)-([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(stack/?)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Works Like charm, I am really happy, Thanks a lot,